# Opencl runs fine even the kernel has errors

Tags: kernel, opencl

I have come across a strange problem.
I have a simple kernel. It works fine.
I found that, if I remove some lines or introduce some errors inside the opencl kernel file and then try to run the program, the program runs fine as if it has the corrected code and does not give any error.
But it should give error as the kernel has error.
So, it cannot detect error and if it finds error it runs with previous correct version's code.
Is this a feature? whats wrong here?

Comment: Post some code about how you build your kernel please.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly feel that you forgot to add OpenCL error checking for each openCL API in your code, If you don't catch the error explicitly OpenCL kernel will simply continue as if there is no issue. (Should never miss this in OpenCL programming)

if you have not done the error checking then can be done as follows (varies based on API calls)

```
error=clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, &platforms);
if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("\n Error number %d", error);
}
```

as you mentioned in the comment that you are getting the right values even if the kernel has error, this is because the device memory or host memory have the result of previous run (this could happens some time). Initialize your output buffer to 0 and then push to gpu and read back, now probably you may see garbled output.

Comment: Initializing 0 did not help. Every time I run the kernel with error I get the result of previous result. Is it the natural way of working for opencl? I am not using clCreateProgramWithBinary.

Comment: Did you applied the API error checking? if so are there any failures? This is not the way OpenCL work, please dump your code for further investigation.

Comment: Hi Sagar,This is the way OpenCL works. If your kernel has errors and it is nto run then the device memory still holds the value from previous successfull run of the code. So, you will have the value from previous run.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a feature of OpenCL. I'm guessing the cause is either:

1. You are not giving `clCreateProgramWithSource` the kernel you think you're giving it. A good way to check this is to print out the string you provide to `clCreateProgramWithSource` immediately before the call.
2. Your application "caches" the kernel and subsequent executions use `clCreateProgramWithBinary` instead of the (modified) kernel source code.

Comment: for simplicity I assigned some values to and array from the kernel. LIke this : c[iGID] = 111; If I remove the semicolon, program still shows me 111. If I change c[iGID] = 222; and put the semicolon back, I see 222. Program is getting the same source. I tried with removing the executables and recompile again. But it still can run perfectly with error inside kernel.

Comment: @Luniam that seems to preclude my first suggestion above, then - check the second one?

Comment: I have removed all the executables and recompiled again. So, it should  start as a new one and should get the changes made in the kernel. BTW, i did not used clCreateProgramWithBinary one in my program.

Comment: @Luniam the built kernel won't be an executable and recompiling should not effect it. But if you're not using `clCreateProgramWithBinary` this option is also not possible so I'm afraid I don't have a solution for you :( I'm leaving my answer here in case it would help anyone else with a similar problem.

Comment: I would say that you are using build with binary, and at any compiling error the program uses the old binary.

Answer (score 1):

The device memory is not cleared between kernel runs or even program launches. Since you are commenting out the code that actually writes the memory, you are just getting what was written there on the previous run. With NVIDIA GPUs and older driver versions I have even seen memory persistence across system reboots.

In order to confirm this you can try to allocate several buffers and launch the wrong kernel with the previously untouched buffer.